# Geometry drawing in WPF

Tags: wpf, pathgeometry

I'm kinda new to all this geometry part, but I can see it gives me the ability to draw basically whatever I want. I can't find a good manual that teaches how to create whatever image I have in my head. I really hoped to find some kinda painter that extracts the data of the geometry for me but no luck so far.

For example, I found this online:

```
<Geometry x:Key="MagnifierIconGeometry">M44,12 C32,12 22,22 22,34 22,46 32,56 44,56 56,56 66,46 66,34 66,22 56,12 44,12z M44,0 C63,0 78,15 78,34 78,53 63,68 44,68 40,68 36.5,67.5 33,66 L32.5,66 14,90 0,79.5 18,55.5 17,55 C13,49 10,42 10,34 10,15 25,0 44,0z</Geometry>
```

You can tell by the name what it draws, but I would like to know how to do it myself?

If anyone could point me to a manual/any kind of program that would be fantastic!

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To display vector graphics, in this case you can use the `Path` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Geometry x:Key="MagnifierIconGeometry">M44,12 C32,12 22,22 22,34 22,46 32,56 44,56 56,56 66,46 66,34 66,22 56,12 44,12z M44,0 C63,0 78,15 78,34 78,53 63,68 44,68 40,68 36.5,67.5 33,66 L32.5,66 14,90 0,79.5 18,55.5 17,55 C13,49 10,42 10,34 10,15 25,0 44,0z</Geometry>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource MagnifierIconGeometry}" 
          Width="30" 
          Height="30" 
          Fill="Aqua"
          Stretch="Fill" />
</Grid>
```

`Output`

[image]

> More info

For more information you can see this:

[`MSDN: Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx)

[`Charles Petzold: Vector Graphics and the WPF Shape Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337899.aspx)

[`Graphics in WPF`](http://www.abhishekshukla.com/windows-presentation-foundation/learn-wpf-part-4-graphics-in-windows-presentation-foundation/)

> Source of vector images

The [`www.modernuiicons.com`](http://www.modernuiicons.com/) contains a huge amount of vector images that you can use in your applications.

> Program for working with vector images

To work with vector graphics you can use [`Microsoft Expression Blend`](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/):

[`MSDN: Drawing overview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295296.aspx)

[`Convert SVG to XAML and use it in Silverlight or WPF`](http://www.uxpassion.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-convert-svg-to-xaml-and-use-it-in-silverlight-or-wpf)

Comment: Perfect! 
exactly what i needed